# How can I write user data to the root partition?

Tags: permissions, filesystem

Another developer created partitions, one with mount point as root and another with mount point as home. Home is full, so I have no option other than to store new files in root.

Problem is, folders created in root always need sudo permissions. Even for copying files into it.

Is there a reason it is this way? For now, I just used `sudo mkdir` to create a folder in root and did a `chmod 777`, but I'm sure that's not the right way to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "root" you mean the root partition (the partition mounted on `/`), then a simple way would be to make a folder somewhere in it that's owned by your user, and then put your files in it.

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/mystuff
sudo chown $USER /opt/mystuff
```

Now `/opt/mystuff` should be writable by you, so use it for your files.

Long term, you should look into resizing the home partition, or moving it to a larger disk.

For convenience, you can make a link to this directory in your home directory:

```
ln -s /opt/mystuff ~
```

Now there will be a `mystuff` directory in your home directory.

Comment: Additionally, the `/opt/mystuff` can be mounted somewhere in the home directory.

Comment: @Melebius: How is that done?

Comment: @Nav IMO a (bind) mount is overkill; a simple link should do: `ln -s /opt/mystuff ~/`. Now there should be a `mystuff` directory in your home directory.

Comment: I like bind mounts, pretty usefull especially if you want to make something available in a tftp pxe start